# how to override .panel-body a {} style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want override the style brought by .panel-body a{....}. I want style the anchor tag in the code snippet differently.

Please suggest a way.

Comment: please post your HTML code

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS selector `.panel-body a`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel-body a {
  /*your css goes here*/
  text-decoration:none;
  background:lightgreen;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="/contest" class="mybtn"><span>CONTESTS</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.